# What does layout location = 1 stand for in the default OpenGL framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have codes like:

```
"#version 330 core\n",
"in vec3 Normal;\n",
"layout(location = 0) out vec4 Colors;\n",
"layout(location = 1) out vec3 rt;\n",
"uniform vec3 light;\n",
"void main()\n",
```

When I'm using the default FBO , I wonder what does layout(location=1) mean?  I suppose location = 0 is pointing to the GL_FRONT or GL_BACK if I'm using double buffers?  Then what does 1 mean?  Is it GL_FRONT if I'm using double buffers?  Otherwise does it mean GL_LEFT?  Or is it simply ignored?

Answer (score 0):

It means the same thing as it would when rendering to an FBO: whatever buffer `glDrawBuffers` *says* that it represents.

Like FBOs, the [Default Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) can have multiple images associated with it. Unlike FBOs, OpenGL itself cannot specify which images are active or where they come from. This is done at context creation time. Default framebuffers can have up to 4 color buffers (front/back with left/right for both) and (in compatibility contexts) potentially multiple auxiliary color buffers.

`glDrawBuffers` is what [creates a mapping from FS output indices to actual buffers in the current framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers). So if you want to know what "1" means, you have to look at the `glDrawBuffers` call and see what index 1 of that array is set to.

If `glDrawBuffers` doesn't route a particular written FS output index to a buffer, this output is discarded.

Comment: Is there a specification about which index must be linked to which color buffer , like 0 is always GL_FRONT for applications that don't have double buffering mechanism ?

Comment: @Shahashahaha: I don't understand your question. I showed you the function which establishes the link between indices and color buffers. I'm sure there's some default state, but good applications should specify it explicitly.

Comment: I meant basically the same as how DrawBuffer array is arranged . Now I know the answer . It is initially only {GL_BACK} (or {GL_FRONT}) for the default framebuffer . So the location of 1 in my question should be ignored.